# Split string into bbcode sections. PHP

Tags: php, regex, phpword

I have a BBcode wysiwyg editor for only the basics styles bold, italic and underline. I need to take the stored data from it and use it to convent it into a PHPWord friendly array.

PHPWord works with something called textrun so to have many styles within a line you would simple do something like...

```
$PHPWordTextRun = new TextRun();
$PHPWordTextRun->addText('This is some text that contains ', 'NORMAL');
$PHPWordTextRun->addText('Italic ', 'ITALIC');
$PHPWordTextRun->addText(' and ', 'NORMAL');
$PHPWordTextRun->addText('bold', 'BOLD');
$PHPWordTextRun->addText('text', 'NORMAL');
```

Im still completely unsure about how i do the nested tags.

So anyway here is what i need help doing. Turning this string below...

```
$string = "This is some text that contains [i]Italic[/i] and [b]bold[/b] text"
```

and turn it into an array like so

```
Array("This is some text that contains ","[i]Italic[/i]","and ","[b]bold[/b]","text");
```

Im a complete novice at regex and not even sure if you would use regex here.

My end goal is to end up with something like...

```
$PHPWordTextRun = new TextRun();
foreach($array as $line) {
    $PHPWordTextRun->addText($line['text'], $line['style']);
}
```

UPDATE:

So after testing around and playng with a couple of the answers i have come up with the following.

As suggested below i have tried the following.

```
$array = preg_split('/(.*?)(\[.+?\].+?\[\/.+?\])(.*?)|(.*)/m', $txt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This is working to a degree but it did have plenty of blanks but fixed with PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY but it doesnt support nested brackets.

Comment: What determines a split?

Comment: If you can put a string description in words, you can easily come up with a regex. If you're completely unversed with it, then it's usually not the best option. And this seems like an unpractical middle step at whatever you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: What about nested tags? For example: `This is some text that [i]contains Italic and [b]bold[/b] text[/i]`

Comment: @Toto Yes you right i havnt thought about that but it is needed indeed, struggling to think about a practicle way to go about this.

Comment: Have look at [BBCode parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php)

Comment: @Toto Thanks for the quick reply and is a very good source, but it will will only parse the tags and replace them, i dont just need the parts in tags, i need the entire string.

Comment: @Mark You can split your bbcode with a regex pattern like this: https://3v4l.org/XGcaG But this seems only suitable for non-nested bb tags.  As stated by Wiktor, implementing a proper BBCode parser is the best way forward.  If your desired data cannot be acquired by a bbcode parser, please post a new question with a challenging sample string (or a few), then state your exact expected output.

Comment: @Wiktor are you planning on hammering https://stackoverflow.com/q/60126022/2943403 too?

Answer (score -1):

This expression might likely return what we wish to output, maybe with slight modifications, if not:

```
(.*?)(\[.+?\].+?\[\/.+?\])(.*?)|(.*)
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(.*?)(\[.+?\].+?\[\/.+?\])(.*?)|(.*)/m';
$str = 'This is some text that contains [i]Italic[/i] and [b]bold[/b] text This is some text that contains [i]Italic[/i] and [b]bold[/b] text This is some text that contains [i]Italic[/i] and [b]bold[/b] text';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/beRkUL/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, best so far, what about nested tags?

Comment: @Emma other users are blindly copy-pasting your regex.  Please tighten your script so that people are using proper coding practices.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126022/create-array-of-classes-from-string-with-bbcodes#comment106342853_60126022  Please explain in plain English what your pattern is doing and why it is appropriate/advisable.

Comment: Better: add a note to only treat this solution as an academic exercise that should never be used in production. Right now, this post only does harm to SO making users believe they can parse bbcode with z single regex like this. There are dedicated libraries to parse bbcode.

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier has no effect on the pattern if there are no `^` or `$` metacharacters in the pattern.  Perhaps you mean to use `s`.